# Prevent scroll on bodies (Matter.js)

Tags: javascript, matter.js

**Background**

I'm trying to achieve something, but it's really driving me crazy. So any help would be appreciated!

I've created a scene in Matter.js that will be placed in a container further down on the page. I want the visitor to be able to interact with the scene, dragging and dropping the bodies. But allowing interaction creates the problem where Matter.js prevents the user from scrolling whenever the mouse is over the canvas.

So to work around this, I'm using the following code:

```
mouseConstraint.mouse.element.removeEventListener("mousewheel", mouseConstraint.mouse.mousewheel);
mouseConstraint.mouse.element.removeEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", mouseConstraint.mouse.mousewheel);
```

This makes it possible for the user to scroll through the page and still being able to interact with the scene by clicking and dragging the bodies, as it's only the scroll event listeners that are being removed. At least on desktop.

**The problem**

However, on mobile, the touch event is the event that makes it possible for the user to scroll on the page, so that would require me to also remove the `touchmove`, `touchstart` and `touchend` event listeners from the mouse constraint in Matter.js. Like this:

```
mouseConstraint.mouse.element.removeEventListener('touchmove', mouseConstraint.mouse.mousemove);
mouseConstraint.mouse.element.removeEventListener('touchstart', mouseConstraint.mouse.mousedown);
mouseConstraint.mouse.element.removeEventListener('touchend', mouseConstraint.mouse.mouseup);
```

And here's where the problem occurs. If I remove the touch events, the user can scroll by the canvas, but the user can't interact with the scene as that requires the touch events to be activated.

So I'm wondering if there is any way to have the touch events added but only allow them to work on certain bodies in the scene? I've found that I can use `mouseConstraint.body` as a boolean in order to know if a body has been clicked/touched or not. Could this be used in some way with this as a base?:

```
Matter.Events.on(mouseConstraint, "mousedown", function(event) {
   if (mouseConstraint.body) {
      console.log("Body clicked!");
   }        
});
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this tobiasg?

Comment: I can't remember if I ever did, unfortunately.

Comment: Oh bummer, thank you regardless.

Comment: FYI, `mouseConstraint.body` has the actual body on it rather than a boolean in recent versions.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I came up with. It's not perfect, but it's better than nothing.

```js
 let touchStart;
  mouseConstraint.mouse.element.addEventListener('touchstart', (event) => {
    if (!mouseConstraint.body) {
      touchStart = event;
    }
  });

  mouseConstraint.mouse.element.addEventListener('touchend', (event) => {
    if (!mouseConstraint.body) {
      const startY = touchStart.changedTouches[0].clientY;
      const endY = event.changedTouches[0].clientY;
      const delta = Math.abs(startY - endY);

      if (delta > 80) {
        window.scrollTo(0, 600);
      }
    }
  });
```

You listen for the touch start event and store that in a variable. Then in the touchend event you check if the swipe is large enough to constitute a scroll, then scroll to the content.